# Браузер не распознает часть CSS кода

Tags: javascript, html, css

В общем проблема такая. Написал небольшой скрипт, и в нем динамически на страницу добавляю через чистый js элементы (чекбокс текст и два дива). Дал этим классам стили, но браузер не видит этот код. Хотя остальную часть видит прекрасно. В обычном режиме стили применяются, но как только я захожу в режим инспектора F12 они сбрасываются до перезагрузки страницы. С чем это может быть связано?

```
.taskBlock{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.check{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.close{
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Этот код в инспекторе просто исчез.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема не в стилях а в медиа-запросах. Когда вы открываете инспектор, разрешение окна браузера довольно существенно изменяется и могут примениться другие стили. Вам необходимо отсоединить инспектор в отдельное окно, чтобы оно не меняло размер окна браузера.

Comment: @DiD Сейчас попробовал и отсоеденить, и просто выставить в настройках разрешения мой монитор, но к сожалению не помогло. Но я попробовал выгрузить на гитхаб пэйджес и там на удивление все нормально работает даже при инспекторе

Comment: Какие ошибки выдаёт консоль? Обратите внимание, там нет скрытых фильтрами строчек?

Comment: Вообще никаких. Скрытых строчек нет. Просто они исчезли

Comment: А как вы их подключаете? Есть атрибут `rel="stylesheet"`? есть ли в заголовках `<!DOCTYPE html>` или что-то подобное?

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода веб-страницы браузер должен создать **[объектная модель документа или DOM](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)** (англ. Document Object Model).
Проверьте **[работу браузера перед выводом веб-страницы](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model)**:

> Перед тем как вывести страницу на экран, браузер создает модели DOM и
> CSSOM... Браузер преобразует HTML-разметку в объектную модель
> документа (DOM), а CSS-разметку - в объектную модель таблицы стилей
> (CSSOM).

Далее проверьте **[влияние javascript на парсинг браузера](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript)**:

> - Выполнение JavaScript невозможно без модели CSSOM.
> - JavaScript препятствует созданию DOM, если не использовать    асинхронизацию.

Таким образом, браузер при создании модель CSSOM использует ваши стили для чебокс и див, исполнение которых скрыто в блокированном скрипте. После разблокирования скрипта, ваши стили уже могут не иметь смысла, потому что DOM и CSSOM уже созданы. Если ваш скрипт имеет асинхронность, то ваши стили могут стартовать только после активации и это также происходит после создания DOM и CSSOM.

Проверьте что говорит **[Википедия о JavaScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)**:

> JavaScript обычно используется как встраиваемый язык для программного
> доступа к объектам приложений. Наиболее широкое применение находит в
> браузерах как язык сценариев для придания интерактивности
> веб-страницам.

В свою очередь стили используются как встроенные в исходный код документа, так и как внешний файл. Не создавайте зависимость стилей от исполнения скрипта.